# Create the Elastic search query to show Random 5 Questions by category

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I Have fields Category & Questions in the Table.

My Requirement is for the below mentioned 3 category against I need the questions which is tagged (SO I want the Category and Questions field in the query) by writing elastic search query

**Category :**

OLA

BNA

DRG

GET logstash-sdc-feedback/_search? { "_source":["Category.keyword"], "size": 5, "query":{ "bool": { "must": [ {"match":{"Category.keyword"": "OLA","BNA","DRG"}}

],

}
}, "aggs": { "MyBuckets": { "terms": { "field": "questions.keyword","Category.keyword" "order":{ "_count": "asc" }, "size": "5"

} } } }

Comment: your question is not quite clear, can you please explain your use case ?

Comment: My Requirement is : I want to show 2 fields (Category & Questions) . In this Category I have to select only this Codes ("OLA","BNA","DRG") for each category codes i need to show the questions as well. How to write the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) along with [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), to achieve your use case.

Adding a working example

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "category": "XYZ",
  "question": "d"
}
{
  "category": "OLA",
  "question": "a"
}
{
  "category": "BNA",
  "question": "b"
}
{
  "category": "DRG",
  "question": "c"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "terms": {
          "category.keyword": [
            "OLA",
            "BNA",
            "DRG"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top_tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_faq_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "question"
              ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "top_tags": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "BNA",                 // note this
          "doc_count": 1,
          "top_faq_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "65566020",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "2",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "question": "b"            // note this
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "DRG",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "top_faq_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "65566020",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "3",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "question": "c"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "OLA",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "top_faq_hits": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "65566020",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "question": "a"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Prabhudas8703 please go through the answer, and let me know if this is what you require?

Comment: I am not getting the output as per your search result. {
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "top_tags" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: @Prabhudas8703 are your field names `Category` and `questions`? (As shown in the query above in the question) In the above query and sample index data, I have taken field names as `category` and `question`. Because of this, you are getting 0 results.

Comment: Yes my field names category and question

Comment: @Prabhudas8703 are you using any index mapping definition? And is the structure of your index data, similar to that given in the answer?

Comment: I dont think so using any index mapping definition. "_index" : "logstash-sdc-faqsearch",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5LKTRDIUYT287139713",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "question" : "A?",
          "answer" : "ABCDEF",
          "source" : "Common",
          "id" : "5fetyui87912531711",
          "category" : "OLA",
          "uuid" : "bb-b6e1-4d7d-acoa-5bc5",
          "relavence_score" : "26.04",
          "timestamp" : 1608558330508

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226830/discussion-between-escoder-and-prabhudas8703).

Comment: Sorry I made the mistake."field": "question.keyword" I put now it is working fine now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Prabhudas8703 glad this worked for you 